# How to insert data into excel table using Apache Calcite?

Tags: java, excel, apache-calcite

I am using Apache Calcite for reading data from excel.
Excel has 'salary' table with following fields

- Integer id
- Integer emp_id
- Integer salary

I have following model.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "defaultSchema": "excelSchema",
  "schemas": [{
      "name" : "excelSchema",
      "type": "custom",
      "factory": "com.syncnicia.testbais.excel.ExcelSchemaFactory",
      "operand": {
        "directory": "sheets/"
      }
    }]
}
```

This is my calcite connection code

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:calcite:model=src/main/resources/model.json");
CalciteConnection calciteConnection = connection.unwrap(CalciteConnection.class);
```

I am able to get data from above connection using following code.

```
Statement st1 = calciteConnection.createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet =   st1.executeQuery("select * from \"excelSchema\".\"salary\"");
System.out.println("SALARY DATA IS");
while (resultSet.next()){
    System.out.println("SALARY data is : ");
    for (int i2 = 1; i2 <= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i2++) {
        System.out.print(resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i2)+" = "+resultSet.getObject(i2)+", ");
    }
}
```

Above code is working fine it shows all entries from salary tables, but when I am trying to insert into same table i.e excel using following code

```
    String insertSql = "INSERT INTO \"excelSchema\".\"salary\" values(5,345,0909944)";
    Statement insertSt = calciteConnection.createStatement();
    boolean insertResult = insertSt.execute(insertSql);
    System.out.println("InsertResult is "+insertResult);
```

I am getting following exception

```
    Exception in execute qry Error while executing SQL "INSERT INTO "employeeSchema"."salary" values(5,345,0909944)": There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties: convention=ENUMERABLE, sort=[].
Missing conversion is LogicalTableModify[convention: NONE -> ENUMERABLE]
There is 1 empty subset: rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[], the relevant part of the original plan is as follows
299:LogicalTableModify(table=[[employeeSchema, salary]], operation=[INSERT], flattened=[false])
  293:LogicalValues(subset=[rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[]], tuples=[[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]])

Root: rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[]
Original rel:
LogicalTableModify(table=[[employeeSchema, salary]], operation=[INSERT], flattened=[false]): rowcount = 1.0, cumulative cost = {2.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 296
  LogicalValues(tuples=[[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]]): rowcount = 1.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 293

Sets:
Set#0, type: RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary)
    rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[], best=null, importance=0.81
        rel#293:LogicalValues.NONE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]](type=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}
    rel#305:Subset#0.ENUMERABLE.[], best=rel#304, importance=0.405
        rel#304:EnumerableValues.ENUMERABLE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]](type=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}
Set#1, type: RecordType(BIGINT ROWCOUNT)
    rel#300:Subset#1.NONE.[], best=null, importance=0.9
        rel#299:LogicalTableModify.NONE.[](input=RelSubset#298,table=[employeeSchema, salary],operation=INSERT,flattened=false), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}
    rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[], best=null, importance=1.0
        rel#303:AbstractConverter.ENUMERABLE.[](input=RelSubset#300,convention=ENUMERABLE,sort=[]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}

Graphviz:
digraph G {
    root [style=filled,label="Root"];
    subgraph cluster0{
        label="Set 0 RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary)";
        rel293 [label="rel#293:LogicalValues.NONE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]\ntype=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        rel304 [label="rel#304:EnumerableValues.ENUMERABLE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]\ntype=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]\nrows=1.0, cost={1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}",color=blue,shape=box]
        subset298 [label="rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[]"]
        subset305 [label="rel#305:Subset#0.ENUMERABLE.[]"]
    }
    subgraph cluster1{
        label="Set 1 RecordType(BIGINT ROWCOUNT)";
        rel299 [label="rel#299:LogicalTableModify\ninput=RelSubset#298,table=[employeeSchema, salary],operation=INSERT,flattened=false\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        rel303 [label="rel#303:AbstractConverter\ninput=RelSubset#300,convention=ENUMERABLE,sort=[]\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        subset300 [label="rel#300:Subset#1.NONE.[]"]
        subset302 [label="rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[]",color=red]
    }
    root -> subset302;
    subset298 -> rel293;
    subset305 -> rel304[color=blue];
    subset300 -> rel299; rel299 -> subset298;
    subset302 -> rel303; rel303 -> subset300;
} caused by org.apache.calcite.plan.RelOptPlanner$CannotPlanException: There are not enough rules to produce a node with desired properties: convention=ENUMERABLE, sort=[].
Missing conversion is LogicalTableModify[convention: NONE -> ENUMERABLE]
There is 1 empty subset: rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[], the relevant part of the original plan is as follows
299:LogicalTableModify(table=[[employeeSchema, salary]], operation=[INSERT], flattened=[false])
  293:LogicalValues(subset=[rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[]], tuples=[[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]])

Root: rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[]
Original rel:
LogicalTableModify(table=[[employeeSchema, salary]], operation=[INSERT], flattened=[false]): rowcount = 1.0, cumulative cost = {2.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 296
  LogicalValues(tuples=[[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]]): rowcount = 1.0, cumulative cost = {1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}, id = 293

Sets:
Set#0, type: RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary)
    rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[], best=null, importance=0.81
        rel#293:LogicalValues.NONE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]](type=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}
    rel#305:Subset#0.ENUMERABLE.[], best=rel#304, importance=0.405
        rel#304:EnumerableValues.ENUMERABLE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]](type=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}
Set#1, type: RecordType(BIGINT ROWCOUNT)
    rel#300:Subset#1.NONE.[], best=null, importance=0.9
        rel#299:LogicalTableModify.NONE.[](input=RelSubset#298,table=[employeeSchema, salary],operation=INSERT,flattened=false), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}
    rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[], best=null, importance=1.0
        rel#303:AbstractConverter.ENUMERABLE.[](input=RelSubset#300,convention=ENUMERABLE,sort=[]), rowcount=1.0, cumulative cost={inf}

Graphviz:
digraph G {
    root [style=filled,label="Root"];
    subgraph cluster0{
        label="Set 0 RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary)";
        rel293 [label="rel#293:LogicalValues.NONE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]\ntype=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        rel304 [label="rel#304:EnumerableValues.ENUMERABLE.[[0, 1, 2], [1, 2], [2]]\ntype=RecordType(INTEGER id, INTEGER emp_id, INTEGER salary),tuples=[{ 5, 345, 909944 }]\nrows=1.0, cost={1.0 rows, 1.0 cpu, 0.0 io}",color=blue,shape=box]
        subset298 [label="rel#298:Subset#0.NONE.[]"]
        subset305 [label="rel#305:Subset#0.ENUMERABLE.[]"]
    }
    subgraph cluster1{
        label="Set 1 RecordType(BIGINT ROWCOUNT)";
        rel299 [label="rel#299:LogicalTableModify\ninput=RelSubset#298,table=[employeeSchema, salary],operation=INSERT,flattened=false\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        rel303 [label="rel#303:AbstractConverter\ninput=RelSubset#300,convention=ENUMERABLE,sort=[]\nrows=1.0, cost={inf}",shape=box]
        subset300 [label="rel#300:Subset#1.NONE.[]"]
        subset302 [label="rel#302:Subset#1.ENUMERABLE.[]",color=red]
    }
    root -> subset302;
    subset298 -> rel293;
    subset305 -> rel304[color=blue];
    subset300 -> rel299; rel299 -> subset298;
    subset302 -> rel303; rel303 -> subset300;
}
```

Please help me with how to insert data into excel using Apache Calcite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately Calcite doesn't support insertion for most of the available adapters. (I believe only for JDBC data sources at the moment.)

Comment: Ok, thank you. So I think I should use Apache POI for data insertion, But is there any other option?

Comment: @subodh3344 There are certainly plenty of other libraries for working with Excel spreadsheets. You would also be welcome to contribute the necessary code to Calcite.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to insert and update in CSV file using apache calcite? If not then can anyone suggest me that which libraries i can use, I need to process large number of data